Remove 'nintendo' and 'commodore' from the console/computer tag names
I don't see the logic in these tag names:

nintendo-switch
nintendo-wii
nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds
nintendo-ds
nintendo-64
nintendo-gamecube
commodore-64

We don't use tag names like:

sony-ps4
microsoft-xbox-360
commodore-amiga
Etc...

And we also use tag names like:

game-boy-advance not nintendo-game-boy-advance
game-boy not nintendo-game-boy
Etc…

Can we remove nintendo from the above tag names and rename the tag commodore-64 to c64?

Related: Tag synonym(s) Nintendo Switch. There are many others regarding the naming convention of platform tags, but I linked that one because Robotnik's answer can be applicable to most Nintendo tags

I've added [tag:c64] as a synonym of [tag:commodore-64] - meaning if you search for it (either as [c64] in the site search or just c64 in the Ask Question page's tag field) you'll get the longer tag. the rest of the changes here are unwarranted as Wondercricket & Daemons have covered :)

I think the reasoning behind this is mainly that we know the "Nintendo DS" as such, and we know the PlayStation as just the "PlayStation" - rarely does anyone call it "Sony('s) PlayStation" specifically.
And if we were to tag the Nintendo DS as just ds, it might introduce new problems as to how clear or descriptive it is (even though, apparently, it is a synonym for nintendo-ds; but it could have referred to Dead Space, as well). Similar to your other examples.
If you compare the main tag names, you'll find they all correspond to their real-life naming conventions. And, for example, Wikipedia follows the same pattern (except for the GameCube, which uses nintendo-gamecube as its main tag on our site).

I’d rather add nintendo as a prefix for tags that don’t have it than remove it for tags that do, for clarity.
I also don’t think we need to shorten the commodore-64 tag when that makes it less clear what we’re talking about, and because there’s no reason to.
Joachim's answer is better. Go look at that.
